# Probability of failure of individual components in parallel and sequential system

Tags: probability, random-variables

[image]

Not sure If I'm calculating these probabilities correctly was wondering if someone could lead me in the right direction otherwise. Probability of a channel working properly is 0.8 and all channels are independent. Random variable X is the number of failed channels:

- P(X=0): 0.8 * (0.8+0.8 - 0.8*0.8) * 0.8 = 0.6144
- P(X=1): 0.8 * (0.2 * 0.8 + 0.2*0.8) * 0.8 = 0.2048
- P(X=2): 0.8 * (0.2 + 0.2) * 0.8 = 0.256
- P(X=3): 0.2 * (0.2 + 0.2) * 0.8 = 0.064
- P(X=4): 0.2 * (0.2 + 0.2) * 0.2 = 0.016

Probabilities don't add up to 1 so I'm not sure where the error in my calculations is at. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I understand the diagram.  Are each of the $k_i$ "channels"?  Looking at it, I'd have said there were exactly two possible channels, in the sense of paths from start to finish:  $k_1\to k_2\to k_4$ and $k_1\to k_3\to  k_4$.  But you seem to suggest that there are $4$ channels.

Comment: What is a channel in this context? If there are $4$ independent channels with equal probability to work, and if $X$ denotes the number of working channels then $X$ has binomial distribution.

Comment: Yes each of the **k** are channels/circuits through which a signal can flow, but the question only pertains to the probabilities of the number of channels failing not the current flow.

Comment: Then what is your motivation for your calculation of $P(X=0)$? Isn't it just $P(X=0)=0.8^4$? (none of the independent channels fails). And in what sense is the diagram relevant (if the flow itself is not relevant)?

Comment: That's what the book gave as the probability of a parallel system not failing. I assumed that equates to both channels working properly.

Comment: "both" channels, you say. But you seem to be thinking of $4$ channels.

Comment: Sorry I meant that the parallel system **k2**, **k3** has that probability. Which is then multiplied by the other channels probability of working.

Comment: What you calculate in the first bullet is the probability that $k_1$ works, that at least one of $k_2$ and $k_3$ works and that $k_4$ works. This is not the same as: $k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4$ all work (corresponding with $X=0$).

Comment: Also there is no obvious event here that has probability $0.2+0.2$ wich is used as a factor in the bullets 3,4,5.

Answer (score 1):

There are four *components*, $k_1, k_2, k_3, k_4$ and these form two 
*channels*, $k_1\to k_2\to k_4$ and $k_1\to k_3\to k_4$.   Then $X$, the count of open channels, can only be in $\{0,1,2\}$.

Let $q_1, q_2, q_3, q_4$ be the independent probabilities of failure of each component (all equal $0.2$), and likewise $p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4$ be the probabilities of success (all equal to $0.8$).   (Labeling lets you check your logic.)

$\mathsf P(X=0) = q_1+p_1q_4+p_1q_2q_3p_4 = 0.3856
\\ \mathsf P(X=1) = 
\\ \mathsf P(X=2) = $

Comment: I think I confused the issue with the use of the word "channels". Thanks to the comments above I realized that the probability of 4 "nodes" failing is equal to **0.2 x 0.2 x 0.2 x 0.2**, and for 3 "nodes" it would be **4 x 0.8 x 0.2 x 0.2 x 0.2**